# ConfigureAwait(false) still deadlocks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've been reading up a bit on `async/await` and was trying to reproduce a deadlock scenario in windows forms by calling `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` on the UI thread and then calling `task.Result` on the UI thread while the task was executing. This resulted in a deadlock.

Then I tried to address the issue by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the returned task, but to my surprise that still caused a deadlock. My understanding is that it should execute the continuation of the method on a different thread and hence there should be no deadlock. What am I missing?

I know how to get around the issue but thought `ConfigureAwait(false)` would fix it as well.

Here is the code, I am using NET 4.5

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Deadlocks!
        Task<string> task = DownloadAsync();
        textBox1.Text = task.Result;

        // Works
        //textBox1.Text = await DownloadAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<string> DownloadAsync()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        string result = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.rpmglobal.com").ConfigureAwait(false);          

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`WebClient` will still cause this deadlock because `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is just a wrapper around the [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) methods, which *always* raise their event in the original context. There's no way to turn this off.

Try using `HttpClient` (or something simple like `Task.Delay`) to see the difference.